# 'Realist 45' film advance lever works more than once per exposure, is this wrong?

Tags: troubleshooting, old-cameras, stereoscopy

I recently got a [Stereo Realist 45 Camera](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Realist_45). Today while shooting I noticed that I can use the film advanced lever more than once before pressing the shutter release button.

Obviously this is not good: if I forget that it's already cocked I'll end up with blank frames. So my question is, is this normal behavior for this type of camera or is mine broken in this regard?

If it is broken, any idea what could be the cause / if the repair is something I could manage on my own?

Comment: I don't know if this necessarily applies to this particular camera, but when I was learning on an old Canon FT-1, IIRC, it often took more than one swing of the advance lever to advance a frame. But after like 1.5-2.0 full swings, it would refuse to move more. Not sure how that was accomplished mechanically, but the principle was kind of like "advance until it stops letting you advance".

Comment: Im pretty sure it would let me advance until the entire roll is used up

Comment: Presumably the camera needs to advance two frames every time, as it's taking them in pairs. Simplest would be to see if it does have a stop if you try to keep winding; otherwise you'll probably be double-exposing the edges of each frame-pair.

Comment: My notion is that was normal behavior for most film cameras.  Certainly of that age, they  let you continue winding the film to the end of the roll regardless of taking any picture or not. Winding the film does cock the shutter spring for next, else the shutter cannot fire again. Some cameras had a double exposure button, so that the wind lever cocked the shutter but did not move the film. I think your camera instead has a cocking button to allow double exposure without winding, above and between the two lenses.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Actually, it's more complicated than that because, In-between the left eye frame and the right eye frame for any given picture, you'll find one frame from the picture before and one frame from the picture after. I don't remember how many sprocket holes the film advances in order to stagger them in that way, but it is the same number every time.

Answer (score 1):

So I took off the top panel of the camera and sort of re-aligned the cover for the spring. A sort of frisbee shaped part.  I put the panel back on and now it stops you from advancing twice between exposures as I would expect.